# How to skip Imacros row if keyword not found (CEO)

Tags: imacros

I'm scraping contact pages where appears word CEO.
Problem: When CEO is not mentioned my code wont compile.

Error:

```
RuntimeError: element * specified by Txt:CEO was not found, line 16 (Error code: -921)
```

My code: (it says When CEO appears on site scrape the next element.)

```
VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX
Tag Pos=1 Type=* Attr=Txt:CEO Content=Event:MouseOver
Tag Pos=R1 Type=* Attr=* Extract=Txt
Set CEO {{!Extract}}
Set !Extract Null
Set FinalVar Eval("var a = '{{CEO}}'; if (a != '#EANF#') { b = a; } else { b = 'Not found!'; } b;")

add !extract {{CEO}}

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=D:\imacro\ FILE=ceos.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be useful to ignore any errors in the following way:

```
'...
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
Tag Pos=1 Type=* Attr=Txt:CEO Content=Event:MouseOver
Tag Pos=R1 Type=* Attr=* Extract=Txt
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 6
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
'...
```